# How to consider bitrate, -maxrate and -bufsize of a video for web

Tags: video, ffmpeg, bitrate

I am using ffmpeg to encode my videos to upload them on the web. I saw [this post](https://www.virag.si/2012/01/web-video-encoding-tutorial-with-ffmpeg-0-9/) about using ffmpeg, but didn't quite get as to how to consider the values.

Suppose I have a video of size 70 MB with a duration of 4 minutes. How would I consider the value for these flags : `-b:v`, `-maxrate` and `-bufsize` for this command?

```
ffmpeg -i input -codec:v libx264 -profile:v main -preset slow -b:v ? -maxrate ? -bufsize ? -vf "scale=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -movflags +faststart output
```

Or is there any normal value, like for the `crf` values are 19-24? I would really appreciate your help and guidance.

Comment: Video encoding is an art, and there are hundreds of parameters to master. Notice that two-pass encoding will offer (much) better quality and compression in most scenarios than playing with bitrates. Ussually the final size and video bitrate depends mainly on the video output size. ffmpeg is ussually smart enough to choose maxrate and bitrate if you tell it to keep the same video quality. Notice also that creating a 480px width video is good enough in most scenarios, and that will save much more bandwidth that playing with bitrates.

Comment: @earizon I agree, video encoding is an art and 480 is usually good enough. However, I also like having higher resolutions available because I don't use a CRT at 640x480 anymore. It is definitely a better way to reduce sizes than fiddling with bitrates, but again, I like options.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It really depends on your upload speed.

`bufsize` will determine how religious ffmpeg is about keeping your bitrate constant. If you set a `bufsize` of 64k, as per [FFmpeg Wiki: Limiting the output bitrate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Limiting%20the%20output%20bitrate), it will calculate its current bitrate every 64 kilobytes and adjust accordingly. Smaller sizes for `bufsize` can be harmful to quality in that they don't allow enough space between checks for x264 to do sudden changes - you will get blockiness.

If your `maxrate` is 640kbps, and your `bufsize` is 64k, then every tenth of a second x264 would check. This is sub-optimal - [FFmpeg Wiki: Encoding for streaming sites](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites) recommends to run it every 1 to 2 seconds. If this didn't make sense, think of it as `maxrate`/`bufsize` = frequency of checks. Keep this frequency between 1 and 2 seconds as a rule of thumb.

If you set both `maxrate` and `bufsize`, you should:

- set `maxrate` to whatever your lowest upload speed will likely be (in the [ffmpeg wiki example](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites), this is 80% of total upload speed, but your mileage may vary).
- set `bufsize` to somewhere between the same as your `maxrate` (one second) and twice of your `maxrate` (2 seconds). If this is still not low enough, lower your `maxrate` and then re-set `bufsize` accordingly.

Then, you'll have to play around a bit, but since you have to start somewhere I'd just start at a `maxrate` around 600k, which was usually satisfying enough for me back before I used `crf` for everything.

If you'd like, you can try lower values for `bufsize`, like for every three or four seconds, just to see how the value changes how your output looks. Then you can determine how much you should worry about it for your video.

There is no normal value, really - what `crf` does is to optimize output based on what it thinks is the best buffer size for maintaining whatever it's rate is set at. It tries to keep as low a file size while maintaining some quality, at the cost of occasional spikes.

Comment: Shouldn't "set bufsize to somewhere between the same as your maxrate (one second) and half of your maxrate (2 seconds)" be "set bufsize to somewhere between the same as your maxrate (one second) and twice your maxrate (2 seconds)" ?

Comment: @Ely I think you are right. Mine would do it every half second. I'll fix that!

Comment: @Wyatt8740 Sorry, I was very busy. Just one question though. If I use `crf`, then I don't need to specify `bitrate`, `buffsize` and `maxrate`? And if so, which is more efficient (use `crf` or `bitrate`, `buffsize` and `maxrate`)?

Comment: @Robin You can use bufsize and maxrate with crf. Remember, crf will adjust bitrate on the fly to match a certain quality, and if parts of the video are very complex, the bitrate will shoot sky-high and you probably don't want that, so better "put a lock" with bufsize and maxrate (but not too strict, or you video will look like crap ! :) )

Comment: @Robin correct, you shouldn't need to use crf with the others. However, you can if you want to constrain it. crf tries to maintain constant quality - you can force it to do so within limits with `bufsize` and `maxrate`. You do not need `bitrate`, though. As Ely said, it will make it better for streaming.

Comment: @Wyatt8740 Ok. I think I am getting this. I just saw this [post](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#CRFwithmaximumbitrate). As you said, the frequency should be between 1 and 2 seconds, but as the `-maxrate` is 400k and `-bufsize` is 1835k, the result is 0.2. What's going on here?

Comment: @Robin  My recommendation was simply a rule of thumb. This example uses a more aggressive (and probably less efficient) rate of checking. It doesn't allow as much fluctuation in quality as mine would - you want to give it some room to fluctuate but not enough that the size deviates significantly minute-to-minute. I'd recommend the 0.5 rule, but that's not to say it cannot be done other ways. With some video sources that don't change much (for example color bars or a still photo), this may be acceptable. But I'd do closer to 0.5 anyway, and if anything go closer to one second instead of lower.